# Bizarre result in definite integration

Tags: integration

Let us take the definite integral

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} 1 + \tan x \mathrm{d}x$$

Let us substitute $1+\tan x=u$. Our lower limit is $1+\tan 0=1$ and upper limit is $1+\tan \pi=1$. Since both the limits are the same,the definite integral should yield a value of $0$.

However,if we just calculate the indefinite integral which is $x+\sec^2 x+c$ and then put the limits,we get the answer $\pi+\sec^2 \pi-0-\sec^2 0=\pi$. What's wrong with the substitution method?

Comment: $\tan x$ is discontinuous at $\pi/2$.

Comment: Beware of the discontinuity of $\tan x$ at $\pi/2$

Comment: The problem is that tangent blows up at $\pi/2$. It's not just that it's discontinuous! :)

Comment: @eyeballfrog thank you for replying. Is there any restriction as to when we can substitute like the one you just mentioned?I mean in general case,when can we not use these substitutions?

Comment: It's much deeper than a substitution problem. The problem is that fundamental theorem of calculus holds only for continous (bounded) functions!

Comment: If the function is unbounded on any closed interval in the interior of the region of integration, you definitely can't. Also be careful when finding indefinite integrals. It's not enough that $F'(x) = f(x)$. $F$ must also be continuous. If the $F$ you find has any jump discontinuities, you'll have to add a step function to it to connect those pieces.

Comment: The integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}( 1 + \tan x) \mathrm{d}x$ is an improper integral because of the pole at $\pi/2$.  That improper integral diverges.  You could attempt a "principal value" integral by taking $\int_{0}^{\pi/2-\epsilon} (1 + \tan x) \mathrm{d}x+\int_{\pi/2+\epsilon}^{\pi} (1 + \tan x) \mathrm{d}x$ and then the limit as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.  Or just look at the graph to see that the p.v. integral is $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that $\tan(x)$ is discontinuous at (or unbounded in a pointed neighbourhood of) $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the issue is that $\tan(x)$ has a simple pole there, so $\tan x$ is not integrable (in the standard sense) over any domain containing a neighbourhood of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. To be clear, $f(x)=\frac{\text{sign}(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ is discontinuous at the origin and unbounded over any pointed neighbourhood of the origin, but it is still integrable in a neighbourhood of the origin.

Also, replying to some comments: the fact that the fundamental theorem of Calculus holds only for certain functions does not give that integrals exists *only* for such functions.

Of course if we consider the principal value of the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\tan(x)\,dx$ we get zero by symmetry:

$$\text{PV}\int_{0}^{\pi}\tan(x)\,dx = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{(0,\pi/2-\varepsilon)\cup(\pi/2+\varepsilon,\pi)}\tan(x)\,dx = 0.$$